# loop to get .nc attribute name

Tags: r, list, loops, variables, assign

I have a list with 10 ".nc" variables. I can get the name of each file using "`nc[[1]]$filename`. I want to get all the 10 names and put it into a vector.
I have tried this loop, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any solution?

```
for(i in 1:length(nc)){k <- c(nc[[i]]$filename)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want, but you could append `k` while using:

```
k <- append(nc[[i]]$filename)
```

After you initialized `k` in your for-loop